# cakephp url is appended with Hash key and random characters

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP i am facing a problem that by pagination any random Key combination will by appended after with Hash Key.

for example
http://stellenangebote25.de

if I click on pagination link, Hash Key + Key Combination will be appended to the link

Comment: Could you describe what a Hash Key and Key Combination are? Can you show what your links look like now, and how you want them to look?

Comment: How you build these links in your "View"? Show some code.